# Re-Render From Child Component After State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So what I want is, whenever I click on any list item the item should get struck. I've changed the state but I'm not sure about how to re-render this with new state. Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

Please don't mind my mistakes, I'm a newbie to this and also suggest me how to do this in better way if needed.

**Child Components**

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(thing => (
          <List
            key={thing.id}
            item={thing}
            items={this.props.items}
            listid={thing.id}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return <li onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.item.item}</li>;
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    const items = this.props.items;
    items[this.props.listid] = {
      item: "<strike>" + event.target.value + "</strike>",
      id: this.props.listid
    };
    console.log(items);

    this.setState({
      items
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `thing` in the parent component? It should be state, and you should move the `handleClick` method to the parent, this way you `setState` in the parent, which will then re-render the children with correct state.

Comment: The biggest mistake here is that you are manually calling `this.render()` **never, ever** do that in React. Re-rendering is automatic and occurs whenever a prop or state changes.

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry. I forgot to remove that it was just an experiment.

Comment: @silencedogood thing is just a local variable in map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep todos state in a parent component, and allow to state change from the inner components.

For example:

App.js (here we keep todos in state, and pass toggle function, and todo items as props to child components:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "todo 1",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "todo 2",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "todo 3",
        completed: true
      }
    ]
  };

  toggle = id => {
    const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        return {
          ...todo,
          completed: !todo.completed
        };
      }
      return todo;
    });

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      todos: updatedTodos
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <TodoList items={this.state.todos} toggle={this.toggle} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(todo => (
          <Todo key={todo.id} item={todo} toggle={this.props.toggle} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Todo.js (here we call toggle function when handleClick, and pass the id of the todo)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Todo extends Component {
  handleClick = id => {
    this.props.toggle(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { id, text, completed } = this.props.item;

    return (
      <li onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)}>
        {completed ? <strike>{text}</strike> : text}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

here is codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-cloud-hmdw0

Comment: Thanks. Now, I know how to pass methods from parent to child.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra good to hear it helped you, can you please accept as answer?

Comment: You can also try adding and removing todos by yourself to learn better.

Comment: Yes my code has add functionality. But I will add remove functionality as well.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra official react docs and  examples section may help, https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200994/discussion-between-abhinav-kushagra-and-suleymansah).